# Creating an empty dataframe in pandas with column of type datetime64[ns, Europe/Paris]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-datetime

I want to create an empty dataframe in pandas with a single column 'time'. I also want it to be of type `datetime64[ns, 'Europe/Paris']`, ie. to be able to store timezone-aware timestamps.

I actually need to return an empty dataframe under certain conditions, but I still want to be able to perform some basic operations that require the type to be defined (for instance, merging it with other similra dataframes / performing group by using the column, and so on...).

For now, the simple `pd.DataFrame(columns=['time'])` creates a column of type `object`.
I tried to use `pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.Series(dtype=np.datetime64)})`, but I get `ValueError: The 'datetime64' dtype has no unit. Please pass in 'datetime64[ns]' instead.` (which I cannot pass by the way). Plus, it would not provide me the appropriate timezone.

Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create empty DataFrame with one column called `time` with default object type and then parse the column with the correct datetime and timezone. See my code below and hope this answer your question:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time": []
})
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"]).dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Paris')
```